# why does it not return JSON to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send JSON format to browser to show.
But it seems like it is not going to broweser plus there is an error like req.write part.
The access url is 127.0.0.1:3000/media=video
i can access to server but it dose not return JSON to browser.

```
var http = require('http');
var recommandCat=['top5','newest','like','random','recommened'];
var url =require('url');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = url_parts.query;
  var returnJson="";
  console.log(query.media);  
   switch (query.media) 
   {
    case 'photo':
        returnJson=photoGenerator();
        break;
        case 'video':
        returnJson=videoGenerator();
        break;
        case 'audio':
        returnJson=audioGenerator();
   }


   console.log(returnJson);
   res.write(returnJson);   


       }).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');


    function videoGenerator()
   {
    var jsonArray = new Array();
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
    var data = new Object();         
     var recoCat = recommandCat[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];        
     data = {
                    tomEngine:{ 
                    mediaType:"video",
                        recommendset:[

                                                    {recommendCat:"+recoCat+",

                                                    recommendResult:[

                                                   {

                                                    mediaId:"",

                                                    mediaEntry:[{
                                                        user1:{
                                                                    name:"sooin",
                                                                    rating:"3",
                                                                    views:"2",
                                                                    like:"ture",
                                                                    comment:"good"                                  
                                                        },
                                                        user2:{
                                                                    name:"sara",
                                                                    rating:"1",
                                                                    views:"4",
                                                                    like:"ture",
                                                                    comment:"good!"                                 
                                                        }                                       
                                                        }], 
                                                    view:"4",
                                                    rating:"4",
                                                    like:"10",
                                                    attribute:{
                                                                    smallUrl:"www",
                                                                    largeUrl:"llll",
                                                                    title:"aaaa"
                                                    },
                                             }]                                                 
                                               }
                        ]   
                    }
        };  
        jsonArray.push(data);
}

return jsonArray;
}
```

Maybe my json format is wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: run your output through: http://jslint.com/ and it will show you what you are missing. For starters all names in the name value pair need to have double quotes around them.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(returnJSON)`  It seems like you need to encode it as a string before calling `res.write`

Comment: @S.Albano is correct, the http server does not automatically convert javascript objects to json. You have to manually encode them. I would submit that as an answer to the question as its what the OP is after. @draford, your also missing a `res.end()`. If you don't call it the server will never close the connection (Till a timeout occurs in the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to send correct **Content-Type** header to client.
Also [**response.end()** should be called in the end of each response](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding).

```
var body = JSON.stringify(returnJson);

res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Length': body.length,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

res.write(body);
res.end();
```

Also if the body of your response is not chunked, you can use only method response.end() like

```
res.end(body);
```